# Question with nested route in Rails3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

there is my route:

```
 namespace :admin do
   resources :products do
      resources :medias do
        collection do
          post :update_positions
        end
      end
   end
 end
```

and I write one form to create media:

```
<%= form_for(admin_product_medias_path(@product), :html => { :multipart => true }) do |form| %>
```

i find that the action of the generated form is "`/admin/products/123213/medias/new"`

I think the rule is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= form_for @product, :url => admin_product_medias_path(@product), :html => { :method => :post, :multipart => true} do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```